# We have two concentric circles. Question

Tags: geometry

We have two concentric circles. Radius of one is 7 cm, of second 11 cm. Smaller circle divides chord of bigger circle so, that it makes three equal parts.
How long is this chord?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be the length of each segment of the chord, d- segment between the circles' centre and the middle of the chord.

$(\frac{a}{2})^2=7^2-d^2, (\frac{3a}{2})^2=11^2-d^2,$

$11^2-7^2=8*(\frac{a}{2})^2$

$a=6$